# WP8 Lazy load items for LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am playing abit around with WP8 development for the first time, but i have a problem, my app will display a verry long list of items, where 1 images is loaded for each item, are there a way to lazy load  the items or images when they are on the screen? I have been looking around but i have not been able to find anything that can do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LongListSelector actually already does that. It only displays the items that are visible on screen. If you want to only actually load those items into memory when they are made visible, you should use the LongListSelector.ItemRealized and ItemUnrealized events to trigger fetching of real data into the item ViewModels.

Comment: Hi Pantaloons, Is there any way to access XAML(ItemTemplate which we set on long list selector) elements inside itemrealized and itemunrealized events.